# how to get the data added verification message at the same page of form

Tags: php

i have this page named courses.php contain the form below (iam using bootstrap):

```
<form class="" action="coumysql.php" method="post" style="margin-left:100px;">
<input type="hidden" name="act" value="add"/>
    <div class="form-group" >
        <label class="control-label" for="course_id">Course Code:</label>
        <div class="" >
            <div class="col-xs-3">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="" name="course_id" required="">
            </div>        
        </div>
    </div> <br>
        <br>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label " for="course_name">Course Name:</label>
            <div class="">
                <div class="col-xs-3">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="pwd" placeholder="" name="course_name" required="">
                </div>
            </div>
    </div><br>


        <br>
            <div class="form-group" style="display: inline;">        
      <div class="col-sm-offset-1 "><br>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Add Subject</button>
      </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

the form processed at the page named coumysql.php

```
<?php
include 'connect.php';

if(isset($_POST['act'])){
    if($_POST['act'] == 'add'){
        if ($mysqli->query("INSERT INTO courses (course_id, course_name) VALUES ('".$_POST['course_id']."', '".$_POST['course_name']."');")) {
    echo "data added";
}
    }else if($_POST['act'] == 'delete'){
        if ($mysqli->query("DELETE FROM courses WHERE course_id= ('".$_POST['course_id']."');")) {
    echo "data deleted";
}
    }


}

?>
```

i want the message "data added" or "data deleted" to be shown in courses.php after successfully form submitted to database

Answer (score 0):

You could create a session() variable and pass it to the view. Like so:

```
 <?php
include 'connect.php';
session_start();

if(isset($_POST['act'])){
    if($_POST['act'] == 'add'){
        if ($mysqli->query("INSERT INTO courses (course_id, course_name) VALUES ('".$_POST['course_id']."', '".$_POST['course_name']."');")) {
            $_SESSION['insert']="Data has been successfully created!";
             header('Location: courses.php');
}
    }else if($_POST['act'] == 'delete'){
        if ($mysqli->query("DELETE FROM courses WHERE course_id= ('".$_POST['course_id']."');")) {
            $_SESSION['delete']="Data has been successfully deleted!";
            header('Location: courses.php');

}
    }

}

?>
```

Then catch them on courses.php like so:

```
<?php
session_start();

$added = $_SESSION['insert'];
$deleted=$_SESSION['delete'];



?>


<form class="" action="coumysql.php" method="post" style="margin-left:100px;">
<input type="hidden" name="act" value="add"/>
    <div class="form-group" >
        <label class="control-label" for="course_id">Course Code:</label>
        <div class="" >
            <div class="col-xs-3">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="" name="course_id" required="">
            </div>        
        </div>
    </div> <br>
        <br>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label " for="course_name">Course Name:</label>
            <div class="">
                <div class="col-xs-3">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="pwd" placeholder="" name="course_name" required="">
                </div>
            </div>
    </div><br>


        <br>
            <div class="form-group" style="display: inline;">        
      <div class="col-sm-offset-1 "><br>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Add Subject</button>
      </div>

            <?php
             if(!empty($added)){
                  ?>
                <div class="alert aler-success"><p><?php echo $added;?></p></div>
             <?php }elseif(!empty($deleted)){
                 ?>
                <div class="alert aler-success"><p><?php echo $deleted;?></p></div>
                <?php
             }?>


    </div>
</form>
```

Note: u can customize `div` tag as u want..